# How to code this javascript into jquery using child-parentnode?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm new to jquery, and i wanted to convert my javascript code that includes two select tags one main and the other for sub, clicking a different option in the main will display a different sub select tag because all of my select tags display are set to none, but i dont know how to structure a jquery

here's my HTML for my select tag

```
   <select name="category" id="c_type" onchange="selectChoice()">
     <option value=""></option>
     <option value="Learning Environment">Learning Environment</option>
     <option value="Learning Support">Learning Support</option>
     <option value="Technology Support">Technology Support</option>
     <option value="Wellness">Wellness, Health, and Nutrition</option>
    <option value="Training">Training and Skills Development</option>
    <option value="Financial">Financial Support and Subsidy</option>
    <option value="Assistive">Assistive Learning Devices for Students with Special Needs</option>

   </select>
   <select name="specifics1" id="LE" style="display:none">
     <option value=""></option>
     <option value="Classroom">Classroom</option>
     <option value="Laboratory Room">Laboratory Room</option>
   </select>
   <select name="specifics2" id="LS" style="display:none">
     <option value=""></option>
     <option value="Lab Equipments">Lab Equipments</option>
     <option value="School Supplies">School Supplies</option>
   </select>
   <select name="specifics3" id="TS" style="display:none">
     <option value=""></option>
    <option value="Computer Units">Computer Units</option>
    <option value="Internet">Internet Connectivity</option>
    </select>
    <select name="specifics4" id="WT" style="display:none">
     <option value=""></option">
    <option value="Feeding">Feeding Program</option>
    <option value="Medical Kits">Medical Kits</option>
    </select>
    <select name="specifics5" id="TAD" style="display:none">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="Pupil Training">Student/Pupil Training</option>
    <option value="Literacy Training">Literacy Training</option>
    </select>
    <select name="specifics6" id="FIN" style="display:none">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="Fare">Fare</option>
    <option value="Meals">Meals</option>
    </select>
    <select name="specifics7" id="ASL" style="display:none">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="Braile">Braile</option>
    <option value="Hearing Aids">Hearing Aids</option>
    </select>
```

finally here is my javascript

```
function selectChoice(){
 var main = document.getElementById("c_type").value;
 var s1 = document.getElementById("LE");
 var s2 = document.getElementById("LS");
 var s3 = document.getElementById("TS");
 var s4 = document.getElementById("WT");
 var s5 = document.getElementById("TAD");
 var s6 = document.getElementById("FIN");
 var s7 = document.getElementById("ASL");
 if(main === "Learning Environment"){
    s1.style.display = "block";
    s2.style.display = "none";
    s3.style.display = "none";
    s4.style.display = "none";
    s5.style.display = "none";
    s6.style.display = "none";
    s7.style.display = "none";
    s1.required = true;
    s2.required = false;
    s3.required = false;
    s4.required = false;
    s5.required = false;
    s6.required = false;
    s7.required = false;
    s1.selectedIndex = 0;
    s2.selectedIndex = 0;
    s3.selectedIndex = 0;
    s4.selectedIndex = 0;
    s5.selectedIndex = 0;
    s6.selectedIndex = 0;
    s7.selectedIndex = 0;

}else if(main === "Learning Support"){
    s1.style.display = "none";
    s2.style.display = "block";
    s3.style.display = "none";
    s4.style.display = "none";
    s5.style.display = "none";
    s6.style.display = "none";
    s7.style.display = "none";
    s1.required = false;
    s2.required = true;
    s3.required = false;
    s4.required = false;
    s5.required = false;
    s6.required = false;
    s7.required = false;
    s1.selectedIndex = 0;
    s2.selectedIndex = 0;
    s3.selectedIndex = 0;
    s4.selectedIndex = 0;
    s5.selectedIndex = 0;
    s6.selectedIndex = 0;
    s7.selectedIndex = 0;

}else if(main === "Technology Support"){
    s1.style.display = "none";
    s2.style.display = "none";
    s3.style.display = "block";
    s4.style.display = "none";
    s5.style.display = "none";
    s6.style.display = "none";
    s7.style.display = "none";
    s1.required = false;
    s2.required = false;
    s3.required = true;
    s4.required = false;
    s5.required = false;
    s6.required = false;
    s7.required = false;
    s1.selectedIndex = 0;
    s2.selectedIndex = 0;
    s3.selectedIndex = 0;
    s4.selectedIndex = 0;
    s5.selectedIndex = 0;
    s6.selectedIndex = 0;
    s7.selectedIndex = 0;

}}
```

Looking at it i have 7 sub select tags with different select names and ids so it will be probably long but its working, what i want is to shorten it using jquery but i don't know how,

Comment: Is your purpose to use jQuery for the sake of using jQuery (which is probably a bad idea), or just to shorten your code?

Comment: @CertainPerformance - well my professor said to use jquery to shorten my code, why is it bad ?

Comment: jQuery won't make this code much shorter. If you're just learning, understanding how built-in JS works is more useful than knowing the syntax of a particular library like jQuery, IMO

Comment: You say you have 7 sub-select tags, but I only see 2, can you post more of the code so we can see if there's a larger pattern from which the logic might be shortenable?

Comment: oh i see, i'll look up more on it, thanks for the advise,

Comment: Can you post more of the code so we can see what might be shortened more?

Comment: Note, if this code already works, then this is much more a question for https://codereview.stackexchange.com than here. Questions about tightening/optimizing/etc. when you code works, but you've been told to clean it up, are definitely something to ask over there, instead.

Comment: i added another line for javascript and HTML basically that's just what i structured out for it, every time the main select tag chooses one option, it will only display the selected category and make the sub select tag required in a form, also the selectedIndex statement was for everytime the user changes the selected option every sub select tag will reset to index 0,

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans ow? so there is also another site like this one? i might as well check it up now, thanks for the link by the way,

Answer (score 1):

IMHO here is the shortest way to write a similar code, and much easier to maintain

```js
const Category = [
  { type:'Learning Environment',                                       ref:'LE',  specs: [ 'Classroom', 'Laboratory Room' ] }
, { type:'Learning Support',                                           ref:'LS',  specs: [ 'Lab Equipments', 'School Supplies' ] }
, { type:'Technology Support',                                         ref:'TS',  specs: [ 'Computer Units', 'Internet Connectivity' ] }
, { type:'Wellness, Health, and Nutrition',                            ref:'WT',  specs: [ 'Feeding Program', 'Medical Kits' ] }
, { type:'Training and Skills Development',                            ref:'TAD', specs: [ 'Student/Pupil Training', 'Literacy Training' ] }
, { type:'Financial Support and Subsidy',                              ref:'FIN', specs: [ 'Fare', 'Meals' ] }
, { type:'Assistive Learning Devices for Students with Special Needs', ref:'ASL', specs: [ 'Braile', 'Hearing Aids' ] }
];


const Select_category = document.querySelector('#c_type')
,     Select_specs    = document.querySelector('#specs')
;

// first initialisation on load...
let item = 0;
Select_category[item++] = new Option('','');
for (let cat of Category)
{
  Select_category[item++] = new Option(cat.type, cat.ref );
}
// ... end initialisation.

Select_category.onchange = function() 
{
  Select_specs.innerHTML = null;

  if (Select_category.value === ''){
    Select_specs.classList.add('noDisplay');
  }
  else
  {
    let item = 0;
    Select_specs[item++] = new Option('','');

    Category.find(cat=>cat.ref===Select_category.value).specs.forEach((spec,index)=>{
      Select_specs[item++] = new Option(spec, index );
    })
    Select_specs.classList.remove('noDisplay');
  }
}
```

```css
.noDisplay { display: none; }
```

```html
<select name="category" id="c_type" ></select>

<select name="specs" id="specs" class="noDisplay"></select>
```